# Find vectors $u, v, w$ such that $span(\{u, v\})=span(\{v, w\})=span(\{u, v, w\})$ and $span(\{u, w\})\neq span(\{u, v, w\})$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, proof-writing

Question:
Find distinct vectors $u, v, w$ such that $span(\{u, v\})=span(\{v, w\})=span(\{u, v, w\})$ and $span(\{u, w\})\neq span(\{u, v, w\})$

Here is my answer:

Starting with $span(\{u, w\})\neq span(\{u, v, w\})$, we see that the addition of the vector $v$ in the span makes then unequal. As the span can not become smaller from the addition of a vector, the inequality suggests that the span on the right-hand side must be *larger*. Since the span has increased, $v$ cannot be linearly dependent on $u$ and $w$. By this, I mean

$v\neq a_1u+a_2w$ for any $a_1, a_2\in \mathbb{F}$.

Now, from the statement $span(\{u, v\})=span(\{v, w\})$, we can conclude that $u$ is linearly dependent on $w$, or vice versa.

$u=a_1w$ or $w=a_2u$ for some $a_1, a_2\in \mathbb{F}$

Now we have a clear set of possibilities that satisfy the question. $v$ must be linearly independent with respect to $u$ and $w$, and $u$ or $w$ are linearly dependent on the other. An example solution is as follows

$u = (2, 0), w = (1, 0), v = (0, 1)$

To check, we may verify that:

$span(u,v) = \mathbb{R}^2$
$span(v,w) = \mathbb{R}^2$
$span(u,v,w) = \mathbb{R}^2$
$span(u,w) = \{(a,0) : a\in\mathbb{R}\}$

This solution is the result of slowly breaking down every part of the problem on a sheet of paper until a reasonable path reveals itself to me. Is there an easier way to go about this problem? Have I overdone the solution or made an error?

Comment: Good explanation of your thought process, which led you to a solution and good justification for your solution.  One issue though: $${} $$ Now, from the statement span$(\{u,v\})=$span$(\{v,w\}$, we can conclude that $u$ is linearly dependent on $w$, or vice versa. $${} $$ You cannot conclude this just from that information.  However you do not need to conclude anything - you are just looking for a solution, not proving it is the only solution.  Instead say "Restricting to the case $u$ is a linear multiple of $w$ means that the statement span$(\{u,v\})=$span$(\{v,w\}$ is automatically satisfied

Comment: Thank you. I must admit I do not understand why you can not conclude that $u$ is linearly dependent on $w$. Is there a counterexample you could give that would illustrate why? Is it something simple I am missing or a larger part of linear algebra I have not yet seen?  
On another note, I am trying to find a large blanket set of rules that allows any set of vectors $\{u,v,w\}$ to satisfy the restrictions of the question. Where did I go wrong in my ending statement "v  must be linearly independent with respect to u and w, and u or w are linearly dependent on the other. "

Comment: If you take all the given information then you can eventually conclude that.  However, if you consider the quoted line in isolation, a counterexample would be: $u=(1,0),\, v=(1,1), \,w=(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach. We now that the inclusion $\subseteq $ holds.

Now assume that there is some $\lambda\,u+\mu\,v+kw$ which lies in span{$u,v,w$} but it does not lie in span{$u,w$}. We already know that

$w$ can be written as $w=au+bv$. So we get a system which we want to

have NO solutions. $\lambda\,u+\mu\,v+kau+kbv=\rho\,u+sau+sbv$. If we

had a solution then we should have $\rho+sa=\lambda+ka$ and

$sb=\mu+kb$. We certainly have $\mu\,\neq\,0$ (otherwise our assumtion

is false), and setting $b=0$ we have no solutions. So $w=au$ which

gives span {$u,v$}=span{$v,w$}=span{$u,v,w$} but

span{$u,w$}=span{$u$}$\neq$ span{$u,v,w$}=span{$u,v$}. (Provided $u,v$

are linearly independent)!!